# Storing Image Thumbnail INTO Image in Android

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, gallery

I am implementing a gallery of images that are stored in a folder in the SD card. The images are copied from the server. I am trying to display thumbnails using the Interface `ExifInterface`. It has a very nice method `getThumbnail`. This method returns a thumbnail if it exists or null if not. But the condition is that the image NEEDS to contain the thumbnail WITHIN.

My Question is: How can I create a thumbnail INSIDE the image when I save the image to SD card so that `ExifInterface.getThumbnail` detects that thumb and does not return `null`

Comment: Thanks for the edit @BackSlash , do you have any suggestions/hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own thumbnail with [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html) class (added in API level 8).

```
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImage);
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(source, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
```

[ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class is very limited, so you cannot attach thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks, this should help with generating the thumb. But what is the mechanism for attaching the thumbnail into the image? How does it work?

Comment: `ExifInterface class is very limited, so you cannot attach thumbnails.` If it was not limited you could add the thumbnail to the exif you read from your image and then write it back. But sadly... Try another exif interface class. But don't blame me when there is no class who can. I don't know.

Comment: Thumbnail is inserted into the image by some cameras. You can't do it by yourself with android library.  
I would suggest you create thumbnail as soon as you download image to SD card and save it with original (append _thumb).

Comment: Okay Thanks for the suggestions. I will try to query the mediastore instead of manually accessing files and see how this goes.